# Get to inside an array which is part of an object without a for loop, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this code that works:

```
var roles = user.getRoles()
   for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++){
      if (Roles[i].getName()== ‘Admin’){
        --gets to this line
   }
}
```

However I was wondering if I could get to a TRUE/FALSE without a for/if loop like the below that isn't working for me:

```
 if (user.getRoles().getName().indexOf('Admin') >-1){
    -does not get to this line
 }
```

Gives error: user.getRoles().getName is not a function

if I print out roles, the return is:
UserRole@718816d, UserRole@1ae91200, UserRole@48baf10b, UserRole@777d6d90, UserRole@34ad99fb, UserRole@6606e47c, UserRole@79ab731e, UserRole@65269056, UserRole@3d9cbf48, UserRole@6ce88983, UserRole@4e792483, UserRole@1f8ca93a

Comment: please add an example of the return value of `user.getRoles()`.

Comment: What is `Roles`? In the first code you check `Roles[i].getName()`, in the second `user.getRoles().getName()`,  so it seems `Roles[i]` and `user.getRoles()` are different

Comment: @Georgy How so? roles = user.getRoles() which is an array of items roles[i] is an index of that array.

Comment: @NinaScholz not really sure why that is needed, it is not non-descriptive ids

Comment: @Edward maybe it's a typo, you have `var roles = user.getRoles()`, but use `Roles[i].getName()`. `Roles` and `roles` are different variables

Answer (score 0):

So what I guess from the provided information is that the method `getName()` is defined on the objects inside the roles array. So `user.getRoles()` returns you an array on which you cannot call `getName()` method

What I think you can do is `user.getRoles().find(el => el.getName() === 'Admin')`

Comment: I forget the name of that type of scripting. Does that run faster, less processing power, than normal for loops with if statements?

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use Array operations `findIndex` or `find`. [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
var roles = user.getRoles()
var i = roles.findIndex(r => r.getName() === 'Admin')
if(i > -1) {
    roles[i] // can access ith element
}
```

Comment: Do you know if this offers any processing speed benefits, over the for loop I mentioned already worked?

Comment: Yes, it behaves as early return, it doesn't have to traverse rest of the items in list once first match is found. So it gives a considerable performance benefit for bigger arrays, doesn't make much of difference for anything less than million items.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using `.includes` should work for you in this situation. You appear to be searching for a known string ('Admin')

```
var roles = user.getRoles()
   if (roles.includes('Admin')) {
       - gets here if true
   }
}
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-array-search-methods

Comment: I tried includes but the it also returned error. I assume the javascript I am working with is an earlier version

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(user.getRoles()?.find(role => role.getName() === 'admin')){
   // do stuff
}
```

The question mark is there to check if there is a value coming from getRoles.

Find will return null or the role.